# What happens if startActivity() is called to the already created Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to start my `MainActivity` with a new `Intent` in my other `Activity`. The two Activities are in the same app, and the second Activity is actually started from the MainActivity. So the scenario is like this:

1. MainActivity is created with an Intent
2. MainActivity starts SecondActivity (but MainActivity is not destroyed yet. It is just stopped)
3. SecondActivity starts MainActivity with a new Intent (SecondActivity is not closed)

The MainActivity is not flagged. I mean, the Activity's launch mode in the manifest is not set (so, it's default).

I want to know what happens to MainActivity's lifecycle and intent.

Is the Activity re-created? Is `onCreate()` called? Then is `onCreate()` called twice, without `onDestory()`? Or the new MainActivity is newly created and there will be two MainActivities? Will the Intent from `getIntent()` overwritten?

I know `Activity.onNewIntent()` is called for singleTop Activities. Then in my situation `onNewIntent()` is not called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: implement all Activity life cycle and test ../

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the Activity re-created? Is onCreate() called? Then is onCreate()
>   called twice,

Yes, yes, and yes, because the default `launchMode` of an activity is `"standard"`. `Activity` with **standard** `launchmode` will create a new instance how many times you want.

> Will the Intent from getIntent() overwritten?

AFAIK, It's still the same `Intent`.

Comment: So new instance of MainActivity is created whenever startActivity is called? Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you call startActivity() for an Activity with default launch mode(i.e, you didn't mention any launch mode in either in manifest or in Intent) a new instance of the activity is created.

For example, A launched B and again B launched A then Activity stack would be A - B - A. Pressing back key at this point would take you to B then A.

Your can refer to [Tasks and BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) documentation from Android.